# Django: Filtering a model that contains a field that stores Regex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models, django-filter

I have a field that stores REGEX patterns and I'm trying to filter the model that it is in by comparing it with a passed in variable called hostname. (Ex: Here I just hard coded the REGEX.

```
Sys_team.objects.filter(hostname= r'^.*\.amgr\..*')
```

I'm met with this error:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'hostname' into field. Choices are: alert, id, pattern, pub_date, sys_team`

The hostname has the format of: xxx.amgr.xxx

Does that mean that only fields can go in the left side of the filter?And if so, is there another way to compare the two with the REGEX pattern on the left side. To reiterate,  hostname is not a field.

Comment: In the left side, yes, only fields from the model you are querying or fields from related models. On the right side you can use `django.models.F` to refer to another field. You can also use `SysTeam.objects.extra` or `SysTeam.objects.raw` in order to make custom queries using raw SQL.

Comment: Yeah, raw SQL came up as a possibility but I was hoping to keep it Django-y. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 20):

Use the Django `__contains` method.

So for your query:

```
Sys_team.objects.filter(hostname__contains='.amgr.')
```

`__contains` is Django ORM's equivalent to SQL's `LIKE` keyword.

Here's the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements

Comment: Only fields can be on the left side of the filter.